# How can I upload photo from angular to .net?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, angular, base64

With this code I can't upload files from angular to .net. I am getting file from input in angular and then I send the form to the .net.

I have registerForm in angular that contains name, lastname, photo and cv and etc. But the photo and the cv are files and I can't send them. I get the following error: ***"The JSON value could not be converted to System.Byte[]."***.

How can I fix it?

```
public class DoctorRegisterDto
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Idnumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }
    public string Categories { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public byte[] Cv { get; set; }
}
public class Doctor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public string Idnumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Categories { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public byte[] Cv { get; set; }
}



    [HttpPost("register-doctor")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<UserDto>> Register([FromBody] DoctorRegisterDto registerDto)
    {
        using var hmac = new HMACSHA512();

        var user = new Doctor
        {
            Firstname = registerDto.Firstname.ToLower(),
            Lastname = registerDto.Lastname.ToLower(),
            Idnumber = registerDto.Idnumber,
            Email = registerDto.Email.ToLower(),
            PasswordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(registerDto.Password)),
            PasswordSalt = hmac.Key,
            Categories = registerDto.Categories,
            Views = 0,
            Description = registerDto.Description,
            Photo = registerDto.Photo,
            Cv = registerDto.Cv
        };
        await _context.Doctors.AddAsync(user);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return new UserDto { Username = user.Firstname, Token = _tokenService.CreateTokenDoctor(user) };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending them through a form try changing the type from byte[] to IFormFile.

Comment: Should I change dto and also entity to IFormFile?

Comment: You can map the data however you want into the entity, but the property type in the dto should be an IFormFile.